# Disable MagicalRecord error messages and warnings

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I just started using MagicalRecord, and this might be a stupid question, but it's really bothering me...
I am using MagicalRecord with sqlite, and when I initiate MagicalRecord, I used

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"OrderSystem.sqlite"];
```

and it produced the following messages:

> 2012-10-16 16:54:48.966 OrderSystem[4135:c07] +NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator: -> Created :  Context *** MAIN THREAD ***

When I tried to store my entity with the following code using a background thread:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){        
    Menu *localMenu = [menu inContext:localContext];        
    localMenu.name = menu.name;
    localMenu.menuid = menu.menuid ;        
}];
```

And I got the following error messages:

> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.118 OrderSystem[4523:4603] +MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler: Error Message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133000.)
>
> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.118 OrderSystem[4523:4603] +MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler: Error Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
>
> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.119 OrderSystem[4523:4603] +MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler: Recovery Suggestion: (null)
>
> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.119 OrderSystem[4523:4603] -NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback: NO CHANGES IN CONTEXT :  Context  - NOT SAVING
>
> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.120 OrderSystem[4523:c07] -NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback: -> Saving : *** DEFAULT**  Context  **MAIN THREAD ***
>
> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.121 OrderSystem[4523:c07] -NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) contextWillSave: Context : *** DEFAULT**  Context  **MAIN THREAD *** is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 1 inserted objects
>
> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.142 OrderSystem[4523:1303] -NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback: -> Saving : *** BACKGROUND SAVE *** Context
>
> 2012-10-16 17:05:20.142 OrderSystem[4523:1303] -NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) contextWillSave: Context : *** BACKGROUND SAVE *** Context  is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 1 inserted objects

When I check my stored data entity using findAll, it does seem to be stored in the database. And if I close the application completely, and relaunch the application, the entity is still there (which suggest the entity had been stored persistently, and not just in the memory). So it seems like everything is working, but any idea what are those error messages? and is there any way to turn them off? or solve them? because it's blocking my other NSLog...

Thank you

Comment: If you are using Cocoapods, this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284067/cocoapods-turning-magicalrecord-logging-off/15284069

Answer (score 31, accepted):

found it. add `#define MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING 0` in your Prefix.pch file before `#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"`

Comment: We've changed the way logging works in the upcoming MagicalRecord 2.3 release — you'll be able to call `[MagicalRecord setLogLevel:MagicalRecordLogLevelOff];` (or a number of other levels) to disable these logging messages once it's released. For pre-2.3 releases, what @hook38 has suggested is the right way to disable logging.

Comment: @Tony Arnold.  Git says my current MR code is up to date as of May 5 14 with "origin/develop".  MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING is no longer having any effect but `[MagicalRecord setLogLevel:]` is not found.  I did find a `setLoggingMask:` in MagicalRecord+Options.m.  What can I do to turn off the normal MR save logging output or turn it back on as needed?

Comment: @chadbag sorry, I had to change the method — here are the docs: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/Logging

Answer (score 20):

In case you use pods add preprocessor macro 
MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING=0
to magical record project like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

**swift**

```
MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Off)
```

**objC**

```
[MagicalRecord setLoggingLevel:MagicalRecordLogLevelOff];
```

put it in your AppDelegate when the application *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*

Comment: Now it seems it's [MagicalRecord setLoggingLevel: MagicalRecordLoggingLevelOff];

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you still have errors to fix. I suggest not ignoring those during development...

Comment: once I turned off record logging, there were no more error messages.

Comment: once I stopped going to the dentist, there were no more cavities.