# Cocoapods: turning MagicalRecord logging off

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, magicalrecord, cocoapods

Turning MagicalRecord logging off requires a #define to be made before it is first included in the project, but in the case of a project managed by Cocoapods I have no access to add a #define in the Pods project. How do I turn logging off completely in this scenario?

Took me a few hours to figure out a way to do it, posting here in the hope it will help others.

EDIT: this is not a duplicate as it discusses turning logging off *under Cocoapods*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable MagicalRecord error messages and warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908584/disable-magicalrecord-error-messages-and-warnings)

Answer (score 79):

You can use a post_install hook to modify pretty much any build setting. Just add this code to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  target = installer.project.targets.find{|t| t.to_s == "Pods-MagicalRecord"}
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        s = config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']
        s = [ '$(inherited)' ] if s == nil;
        s.push('MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING=0') if config.to_s == "Debug";
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = s
    end
end
```

Note that this will only disable logging in the **debug** configuration - logging is disabled by default in the **release** configuration.

Comment: No worries! Would love to hear other approaches to this problem.

Comment: Since I rarely run `pod update` I simply added it to my pods pch file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm not very familiar with ruby, but it seems you have a typo on the line

if s==nil : s = [ '$(inherited)' ] end
          
The : symbol is not necessary.

I removed it and everything started working.

Comment: THANKS!!! I was really getting crazy on this one! :)

It's worth keeping an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/833) on the CocoaPods repo, which seems to be discussing a better way to do this in the future

Comment: Re: typo - you could just put `s ||= [ '$(inherited)' ]`.

Comment: However, this solution doesn't work for me - I'm on MagicalRecord 2.1.  I can't seem to silence the logs even by hacking the pod's .pch file either. I'm on CocoaPods 0.25.0

Comment: [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: Podfile:16: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
    if s==nil : s = [ '$(inherited)' ] end

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I was building a library that depended on MagicalRecord. I didn't want my users to have to add a post_install in their Podfile to silence the noisy logging, so I added it to my podspec instead.

```
  s.prefix_header_contents = '#define MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING 0'
```

This automatically adds this `#define` statement to Pods-prefix.pch, which silences MagicalRecord logging in projects that use my pod.

Answer (score 5):

I updated ank's answer for those using the new cocoapods version alongside MagicalRecord 2.3.0:

```
post_install do |installer|
  target = installer.pods_project.targets.find{|t| t.to_s == "MagicalRecord"}
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    s = config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']
    s = [ '$(inherited)' ] if s == nil;
    s.push('MR_LOGGING_DISABLED=1') if config.to_s == "Debug";
    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = s
  end
end
```

Changes:

- `project` renamed to `pods_project`
- Target `Pods-MagicalRecord` renamed to `MagicalRecord`
- Macro `MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING` renamed to `MR_LOGGING_DISABLED` and value changed from `0` to `1`

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off logging in Pod project!

Simply add Preprocessor Macros:

1. Just go into "Pods" (!!!) project.
2. Then find out Pods-MagicalRecord target.
3. Choose "Build Settings" tab
4. Find "Apple LLVM 6.1 Preprocessing" -> "Processor Macros"
5. Rollout "Processor Macros" and add to "Debug" schema: "MR_ENABLE_ACTIVE_RECORD_LOGGING=0"

It`s all!

Comment: As soon as you run `pod update` this will stop working :(

Answer (score 0):

For the development branch (version 2.3.0 and higher) of Magical Record logging seems to still not work correctly. When imported like this:
pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord', :branch => 'develop'

I have no logging output on my Xcode console. But I altered the post_install script of the Cocoapod. The following should enable logging:
https://gist.github.com/Blackjacx/e5f3d62d611ce435775e

With that buildsetting included in GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS logging of Magical Record can be controlled in 2.3.0++ by using [MagicalRecord setLoggingLevel:]